# ZF2 - how to correctly set headers?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, http-headers

I have problem with setting headers in ZF2. My code looks like this:

```
public function xmlAction()
{
    $headers = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
    $headers->clearHeaders();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-type', 'application/xml');

    echo $file; // xml file content
    exit;
}
```

But headers are still text/html. I can set the proper header with:

```
header("Content-type: application/xml");
```

but I would like to do it with Zend Framework. Why code above doesn't work?

Answer (score 15):

What you are doing is setting headers in a ZF2 `Response` object, but this response is later on *never used*. You are echoing a file and then exiting, so there is no chance for ZF2 to send the response (with its headers).

You *have to* use the response to send the file, which you can do like this:

```
public function xmlAction()
{
    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    $response->setContent($file);

    return $response;
}
```

The idea of returning the response from a controller method is called "short circuiting" and is [explained in the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.examples.html#returning-early)

Answer (score -1):

Try -

```
public function xmlAction()
{
    $this->getResponse()->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array('Content-type' => 'application/xml'));

    echo $file; // xml file content
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Nope, still the same unfortunatelly.